# Mini Cart Close jQuery

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, mini-cart

Where is jQuery function written for **closing mini cart button** in Magento.

I want to implement it while clicking "Continue Shopping" link present in the same mini cart.

Currently my cart **fades in and out as per hover effect**. I wanna close my cart while clicking that link without affecting the hover action happening now.

Answer (score 2):

In default Magento-1.9 installation, `skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js` is what manages cart-box in the header section.

However by default, the cart section has only *click effect*, not *hover effect*. So I assume there is a custom extension or theme involving in your Magento installation. If that is the case, there may be a chance to use different js file to manage cart-box. Just keep this in mind.